# Excel Pivot with "and" operator

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Not sure I've titled this intelligently, but here is what I've been trying to do. I think I have to rearrange the raw data I've been given to make it work, but...

I've been given a list with these columns: product feature, product family, customer, customer size, state.

(so customer A who has 5 product features in 2 product families is in the list five times)

I need to produce a pivot report of customers with the names of all product features they have regardless of the product families those features belong to-- but only for the customers who have at least one product in Family 1 **and** Family 2 **and** Family 3. Then if mgmt wants to look at it by size or state, they can go from there.

There are 50+ features in 20 or so families, so attempts at flattening it across more columns hasn't helped me so far.

Do I need to be doing this in a data model instead of just a plain pivot? Something else? I'll research any suggestions you have.

Comment: Good Day, I tried visualizing your problem and drafting up a quick model to add a column to the base data to help, but it didn't start well. Are you able to provide a small sample screen cap. That might help with things. The other question is Have you looked into using Power Pivot? Best Regards,
Brad

Comment: I wondered about Power Pivot. I'm going to try ZygD's suggestion below first. I knew I was just overthinking and missing a piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better ways of doing it, but this is what I think. I would create 1 additional column where I would indicate if I want that row to be included in the pivot or not. 
[image: filter formula for pivot]

`1` means that the row is included, `0` - the row is not included.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(1,($C$2:$C$11=C2)*($B$2:$B$11="fam1"),0)
           *MATCH(1,($C$2:$C$11=C2)*($B$2:$B$11="fam2"),0)
           *MATCH(1,($C$2:$C$11=C2)*($B$2:$B$11="fam3"),0),1),0)
```

This is an *array* formula, which is entered not with regular <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Also, in the formula, `"fam1"`, `"fam2"` and `"fam3"` must be changed with the family names that you need.

Then this column can be included in in the filters area of the pivot.

[image: pivot]

Comment: I'll try this, but I may even be able to simplify the if in the original table because if that customer name scores a 3 or more than bingo. I'll post what I end up with. Thanks!

Comment: You need specifically "family1", "family2" and "family3" OR you need 3 or more families for one customer?

Comment: I will end up needing to tweak the choices of family, but it would always be customers who have "specifically this, that, AND the other". Not just any 3 or more. That one I figured out.

Comment: Also - this ended up perfect!